# How to properly pass a variable in bash for Ubuntu for API call?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, soda

I am looking to pass a variable through bash to an api call to download a file. How do I properly pass variables to an http call? Below is my bash file:

```
#!/bin/bash

#rm existing file
rm Desktop/ems/ems_raw_update.csv

#create a yesterday variable looking back 120 days
yesterday=$(date -d "$date -120 days" +"%Y-%m-%d")

#download data using that 120 days lookback
echo $yesterday | curl https://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/76xm-jjuj.csv?$where=incident_datetime>='$yesterday' -o Desktop/ems/ems_raw_update.csv
```

The download fails I am assuming because of the way i've passed the variable $yesterday. For example entering the following into your browser will download the proper file:

```
https://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/76xm-jjuj.csv?$where=incident_datetime>=‘2019-12-25’
```

I also note that in my directory i can see the $yesterday variable.

```
total 3.8G
-rw-rw-r-- 1 me   me    0 Mar 22 19:48 =2019-11-23
-rw-rw-r-- 1 me   me    0 Mar 22 19:46 =2019-12-30
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root     root    488 Mar 23 13:12 downloader.sh
-rw-rw-r-- 1 postgres me 3.8G Mar 22 12:17 ems_raw.csv
-rw-rw-r-- 1 me   me   64 Mar 23 12:51 ems_raw_update.csv
-rw-rw-r-- 1 me   me    0 Mar 23 13:12 =$yesterday
```

How do I download this file properly and make sure i remove local variables?

Comment: See: [Difference between single and double quotes in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/3776858)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
curl "https://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/76xm-jjuj.csv?\$where=incident_datetime>='$yesterday'" -o Desktop/ems/ems_raw_update.csv
```

Explanation: Inside double-quotes, the shell will recognize `$` as initiating variable substitution, so `$yesterday` will be expanded to the variable's value. It would not be expanded in single-quotes, and it *looks* like it's in single-quotes here, but since the single-quotes are themselves inside a double-quoted section, they don't have any meaning; they're just normal characters (and will get passed to `curl` as part of the URL argument). The `?` and the `>` (in `>=`) are also special characters in shell syntax, but again the double-quotes make them just normal characters.

The `$` in `$where=incident_datetime` is a different story. As I said, inside double-quotes, `$` is treated as starting a substitution, so by itself the shell would try to expand a shell variable named `where` (which probably doesn't exist, so it'd come out blank). Escaping it with a backslash (`\$where=incident_datetime`) prevents this, turning it into just a normal character to be passed to `curl` (which will pass it to the server as part of the URL, and that'll presumably treat it as part of a database query).

It would also be possible to mix quoting modes: put parts of the URL in single-quotes and the part with the variable in double-quotes, but IMO this is more confusing in cases like this.

Oh, and don't try to pipe the variable to `curl` (the `echo $yesterday |`) part. That's for things that read data from their input stream, which `curl` doesn't (unless you tell it to, which you shouldn't here -- it's not relevant).

BTW, in your example browser URL, there are curly unicode quotes around the date value. I presume this is unintentional (due to some text editor "helpfully" converting them), and plain ASCII quotes are intended. If not, replace them as needed.